# LINQ to SQL vs. SQL Server Reporting Services, which one is good enough for the following?

Tags: sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql, reportingservices-2005

Basic reporting on content usage including time spent viewing a media asset, progress and interactivity based on % complete or correct for up to tens of thousands of users. Basic table and text based reports. Everything is in a SQL Server 2005 database. To me I don't feel like I should have trouble optimizing the LINQ to SQL to be good enough for this, but would there be a great gain from harnessing the Reporting Services? My initial thought is that the amount of effort would be higher and that I won't be able to achieve much more than what is possible with LINQ given the type of data and basic reports I am generating. Anyone have experience with this?

Comment: To me this is sort of like asking "Which should I get, a Ford Focus or build a car of my own?"

Comment: ah the missing piece of the puzzle is that the car is already built, and it might not be worth going for the Fusion at this point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd prefer you to go with SSRS but only because you yourself have agreed that you don't have to be efficiency centric. Linq2Sql is a good option but SSRS provides a very MS-way of doing this stuff. You have a good GUI, wizards, easy configurability.

The advantages of SSRS are not only in the ease of development but also in maintaining and tweaking the reports. Your reports won't be static and may change over time. And tweaking reports in SSRS is MUCH easier and can be done by a novice also. The RDL format is XML-based which is also an advantage. You can always share it and collaborate easily.

To Summarize:

**SSRS**
*Pros:*
Ease of use
Can be developed/changed by novice uesrs
Good for maintainability
Nice for graphic-based reports too
*Cons:*
Speed
S/w Cost :)

**Linq2Sql**
*Pros:*
Speed
*Cons:*
Expertise required to develop/maintain/change
Difficult in changing

Comment: when you say ease of use, does that include implementing it into ASP.NET MVC web app for example?

Comment: What I mean by ease of use is that the expertise required in "Creating/Changing/Modifying" the report and not in its correlation with MVC or others. Nevertheless, I think it should work well in MVC too.

Answer (score 0):

I would not choose reporting services based on efficiency only. SSRS has a ton of features that you may or may not need. If efficiency is your only decision, then I would say it is between LINQ2SQL and just running a query to the DB through a stored procedure.